# CSS Animation Line Grow on Hover

Tags: css, animation, hover, keyframe

I have a button that needs animation when hovered. The image below shows the word "Read More" i would like for the yellow line to the right to expand to about %50 more than its current size on hover.

[image]

```
<a href="#" class="read_more">Read More </a> .read_more { font-family: "Gotham SSm A", "Gotham SSm B"; font-size: 20px; color: #002c77; letter-spacing: 0; text-align: center; line-height: 28px; font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase; } .read_more::after { content: "\2014"; color: #fcd450; }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please attach your code.

Comment: Expand how? In what dimension? All dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below. Hope this helps

```css
.read_more {
  font-family: "Gotham SSm A", "Gotham SSm B";
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #002c77;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  height: 3px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

div:hover:after {
  width: 30px;
  right: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div><a href="#" class="read_more">Read More</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code since it doesn't look like you have anything, but

```
.line {
  width: 100px;
  transition: width .5s ease-in-out;
}
.line:hover {
  width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: I should've added my code, sorry. 

<a href="#" class="read_more">Read More </a>



.read_more {
    font-family: "Gotham SSm A", "Gotham SSm B";
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #002c77;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.read_more::after {
    content: "\2014";
    color: #fcd450;
}

Comment: Put this in your question, this is not at all helpful in the comment section

Answer (score 0):

Based on your own code, I think this achieves what you're after! :)

Once you paste it into your own project the font and whatnot will work.

```css
.read_more {
  font-family: "Gotham SSm A", "Gotham SSm B";
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #002c77;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.read_more:after {
  content: '';
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 12px;
  background-color: #fcd450;
  transition: width 0.3s ease;
}
.read_more:hover:after {
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="read_more">Read More </a>
```